# Converting Velocity and Position Vectors to Longitude and Latitude?

Tags: java, math, gps, physics, latitude-longitude

I've been having a play with a satellite tracking program. You give it the TLE information and the Julian date and it returns the Position Vector and Velocity Vector in 3 parts for the given satellite. For instance the ISS's position and velocity vector at time of writing this are:

```
Position Vector:
1.43201229062465434E18
-2.13926476354018432E17
-9.0494444352008358E17

Velocity Vector:
3.191614378202316E-10
3.0853260273024627E-10
2.1811338307505537E-10
```

I wanted to look this up against a online tracker as a Longitude and Latitude and check that its correct. But I've no idea how to convert these to long and lat. Can any rocket scientists help me out? Is it even possible?

Comment: well longitude and latitude are positional so your velocity vector is not needed.

Comment: Well this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=PJLlWzMBKjkC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174) might get you close.

Comment: This is why I need a rocket scientist to help. Thats well beyond my math skills!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Orbital positions are typically expressed in [Earth Centered Earth Fixed (ECEF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) (Cartesian) coordinates.  You appear to want to convert that representation to Latitude Longitude Altitude (LLA) representation.  Mathworks has a nice description of the conversion [from ECEF to LLA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/aeroblks/ecefpositiontolla.html?nocookie=true) and [from LLA to ECEF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html?nocookie=true).  The Naval Postgraduate School has a [web application](http://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/coord/llhxyz.htm) to convert between the two representations.

For orbital dynamics, the time doesn't really enter into the conversion between ECEF and LLA.  That is only used to determine where the object in orbit is at that point in time (typically in ECEF).  Also, the velocity vector changes over time as the object orbits the earth, but that doesn't have an impact on the conversion either.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure if the output from the program is correct because I'm able to check it with that web application and the ECEF it generates are massively different from the ones the program does if I use the known Lat and Longitute of the given time to generate them. I've converted from GigaMeters to KiloMeters as the program outputs in GM. I'll keep investigating, thanks for the links.

Answer (score 4):

first ensure that the position vectors are in ECEF or in ECI frame..... If it is in ECEF, covert it directly to Lat Long Alt. In case of ECI, convert it to ECEF frame by calculating local sidereal time using julian date and then proceed with ECEF2LLA conversion...